# Create an azure linux VM with terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-virtual-machine

I am using resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" as part of main.tf to create a linux vm. The vm gets created but I want to specify cpu and memory for the vm. I am not able to find specific config to be used for this. Can anyone help on this?

code shared below takes name but not cpu and memory:

````
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "my_terraform_vm" {
  name                  = local.conf.name
  cpu                   = local.conf.cpu
  memory                = local.conf.memory
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.adopipe_terraform_nic.id]
  size                  = "Standard_DS1_v2"
} ```
````

Comment: please share the code you tried soo far @Stack_IQ

Comment: Added...the name part works fine but not cpu and memory

Comment: Is there a way that we can define cpu and memory as part of vm configuration? Can you suggest soemthing?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to Create an azure linux VM by specifing the CPU and memory using with terraform and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

You could create a Terraform module that includes conditional logic to select a VM size based on input variables for CPU and memory.

This approach involves creating a mapping within the module and then using it to set the `size` attribute in the `azurerm_linux_virtual_machine` resource.

**My file structure:**

```
├── main.tf
├── variables.tf
└── modules
      └── vm_selector
            ├── main.tf
```

**My Terraform configuration:**

##### main.tf:

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "myVKnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                 = "myVKSubnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  name                = "myVKNIC"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

module "vm_selector" {
  source = "./modules/vm_selector"

  desired_cpu    = var.desired_cpu
  desired_memory = var.desired_memory
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name                  = var.vm_name
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  size                  = module.vm_selector.selected_vm_size
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.nic.id]

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "18.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  admin_username = var.admin_username
  admin_password = var.admin_password

  disable_password_authentication = false
}

output "selected_vm_size" {
  value = module.vm_selector.selected_vm_size
}
```

##### variables.tf:

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  type    = string
  default = "demorg-vk"
}

variable "location" {
  type    = string
  default = "East US"
}

variable "vm_name" {
  type    = string
  default = "myvkVM"
}

variable "admin_username" {
  type    = string
  default = "adminuser"
}

variable "admin_password" {
  type    = string
  default = "yourstorngpassword"
}

variable "desired_cpu" {
  type    = number
  default = 2
}

variable "desired_memory" {
  type    = number
  default = 4
}
```

**modules/vm_selector/main.tf**:

```
variable "desired_cpu" {}
variable "desired_memory" {}

locals {
  vm_sizes = {
    "Standard_B1s": {"cpu": 1, "memory": 1},
    "Standard_B2s": {"cpu": 2, "memory": 4},
    "Standard_B4ms": {"cpu": 4, "memory": 16},
    # Add more VM sizes as needed
  }

  selected_vm_size = try(
    { for size, specs in local.vm_sizes :
      size => specs if specs.cpu == var.desired_cpu && specs.memory == var.desired_memory
    }[0],
    "Standard_B2s" # Default VM size if no match is found
  )
}

output "selected_vm_size" {
  value = local.selected_vm_size
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

This setup allows you to provision an Azure Linux virtual machine with a VM size that closely matches your desired CPU and memory requirements. The module `vm_selector` handles the logic of selecting the VM size, and the main configuration provisions the necessary resources including the resource group, networking components, and the VM itself.